# How do I go about customizing Mezzanine-Cartridge shop/product?

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, cartridge

I have a few Cartridge starter questions:

My products don't need ratings or dates published. They will never go on sale. Some of the products are downloadable and hence 'num_in_stock' is not relevant or essentially, unlimited. There are no color options, only size.

If I needed to add fields I understand that I could use Mezzanine field injection technique using **EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS(...)**, but I need to be able to deactive or remove them.

I don't see variables pertaining to these changes in the settings module and hence I understand that I would have to customize 'shop'. Can some one please direct me to some documentation on how to customize a Cartridge/Mezzanine module?

Is is just as the Mezzanine doc describes how to go about 'Page/Books/Author'? I understand that for templates and static files we have 'collectstatic' and 'collecttemplates'. What is the equivalent for module code? Do I make a copy of entire cartridge.shop into my workspace and work on it as a module or extend cartridge.shop in my own apps?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Python: 2.7.2
```

Pip freeze:

```
Cartridge==0.8.2
Django==1.5.4
Fabric==1.8.0
Mezzanine==1.4.16
PIL==1.1.7
Pillow==2.2.1
South==0.8.2
argparse==1.2.1
bleach==1.2.2
cartridge-stripe==0.1.3
distribute==0.6.34
django-zebra==0.4.3
ecdsa==0.9
filebrowser-safe==0.2.30
grappelli-safe==0.2.22
gunicorn==18.0
html5lib==0.95
oauthlib==0.6.0
paramiko==1.12.0
pisa==3.0.33
psycopg2==2.5.1
pycrypto==2.6
pytz==2013.7
requests==1.2.3
requests-oauthlib==0.3.3
stripe==1.9.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Answer (score 6):

This >> [mezzanine configuration](https://jupo.org/docs/configuration.html)

And This >> [cartridge configuration](http://cartridge.jupo.org/configuration.html)

may help u to configure cartridge.

And for other customizations :

1. U may override cartridge templates or theme in some of your django
   module for focusing on that.
2. U may  inject fields, or u may hide them
3. U may hook payment steps and some other things
4. If u want some more u may make a monkey patch the mezzanine /
   cartridge code.

If u are familiar to django be sure all steps are easy. I did all of them before and trust me it is really easy.

Comment: That did it! I was able to fix a lot of my concerns with the settings variables. The rest, I should be able to handle in my models and views. Thank you very much, that was a lot of help!